# How to convert all values of list into integers?

Tags: python, list

Hitting a huge roadblock because I can't seem to convert this list into integers.

```
grades = [
    # First line is the descriptive header. Subsequent lines hold data
    ['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
    ['Thorny', '100', '90', '80'],
    ['Mac', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['Farva', '45', '56', '67'],
    ['Rabbit', '59', '61', '67'],
    ['Ursula', '73', '79', '83'],
    ['Foster', '89', '97', '101']
]

values = [data[1:] for data in grades[1:]]
```

When I try to convert values to be all integers, I keep getting errors
I have tried...

```
val=int(x) for x in values
```

and...

```
int_list = map(int, values)
print(list(int_list))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try this : `[list(map(int,v)) for v in values]` OR `[[int(v) for v in val] for val in values ]`, values is list of lists.

Comment: Do you care which grade belongs to which person?  Do you just want `[100, 90, 80, 88, 99, 111, 45, 56, 67, 59, 61, 67, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`values` is a list of lists:

```py
>>> values
[['100', '90', '80'], ['88', '99', '111'], ['45', '56', '67'], ['59', '61', '67'], ['73', '79', '83'], ['89', '97', '101']]
```

so you'll need to iterate through that:

```py
>>> [list(map(int, value)) for value in values]
[[100, 90, 80], [88, 99, 111], [45, 56, 67], [59, 61, 67], [73, 79, 83], [89, 97, 101]]
```

Comment: `>>> [int(e) for value in values for e in value]`

Answer (score 3):

When getting the `values`, you can directly cast them to `int`, e.g.,

```py
values = [data[:1] + [int(v) for v in data[1:]] for data in grades[1:]]
```

or using destructuring and the `*`-operator:

```py
values = [[name, *map(int, data)] for name, *data in grades[1:]]
```